# Why does JobBuilder says could not autowire?

Tags: spring-batch

I am following this Udemy course(Batch Processing with Spring Batch & Spring Boot
) for Spring Batch. In the course JBF(JobBuilderFactory) is depracated so I googled what to use instead and it says use JobBuilder.

Right now jobBuilder and stepBuilder are underlined red and says could not autowired.

```
package com.example.springbatch;

import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
//1st step
@EnableBatchProcessing
//2nd //use of this?
@ComponentScan("com.example.config") //job and steps will go in this packet
public class SpringBatchApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBatchApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
package com.example.config;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.StepContribution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.job.builder.JobBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.ChunkContext;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.builder.StepBuilder;
import org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.Tasklet;
import org.springframework.batch.repeat.RepeatStatus;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration //add annot
public class SampleJob { //3rd creating first samp job

    //5th Create the job, spring batch provides one class - job builder. And create the obj named jobBuilder
    @Autowired
    private JobBuilder jobBuilder;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilder stepBuilder;

    @Bean //4th define @Bean for the first job
    public Job firstJob() { //Job(interface) imports core.Job
        //6th use
        return jobBuilder.get("First Job") //use get First Job is 1st job name
                .start(firstStep()) //Inside the start, pass in your step. Job can hava single or multiple step
                .build();
    }

    @Bean //7th Adding the Step interface. Autowire it as well.
    Step firstStep() {
        return stepBuilder.get("First Step")
                .tasklet(firstTask()) //Will need to call Tasklet.
                .build(); //call build to create the step.

    }

    //8th
    private Tasklet firstTask() {
        return new Tasklet() {
            @Override
            public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution stepContribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
                System.out.println("This is first tasklet step");
                return RepeatStatus.FINISHED; //need this
            }
        };
    }



}
```

I tried to search on google and this is suppose to print System.out.println("This is first tasklet step");

Answer (score 1):

The course is probably using Spring Batch 4. In Spring Batch 5, those builder factories were deprecated for removal and are not exposed as beans in the application context by the `@EnableBatchProcessing` annotation. Here is the relevant section in the migration guide about that: [JobBuilderFactory and StepBuilderFactory bean exposure/configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/wiki/Spring-Batch-5.0-Migration-Guide#jobbuilderfactory-and-stepbuilderfactory-bean-exposureconfiguration).

The typical migration path from v4 to v5 in that regard is as follows:

```
// Sample with v4
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(Step step) {
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("myJob")
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

}
```

```
// Sample with v5
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJobConfig {

    @Bean
    public Job myJob(JobRepository jobRepository, Step step) {
        return new JobBuilder("myJob", jobRepository)
                .start(step)
                .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Mahalo!! Will try this.